# Angular doesn't concatenate value in routerLink

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, session-storage, angular-routerlink

The problem is simple, I have this component, that gets the last searched items I saved in the sessionSotrage, which is an array of ListItem objects:

```
export class SearchlistComponent {
   results = JSON.parse(<string>sessionStorage.getItem("lastSearch"));

}
```

And the html just prints them with the according link to access the pages via routing:

```
<ul class="list-group mt-3">
 <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let result of results">
   <div *ngIf="result.itemType == 'hospital'">
     <div  routerLink='/hospital/{{result.itemId}}'>
       <h4>{{result.itemName}}</h4>
       <h5>{{result.itemLocation}}</h5>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="result.itemType == 'ward'">
     <div routerLink='/ward/{{result.itemId}}'>
       <h4>{{result.itemName}}</h4>
       <h5>{{result.itemLocation}}</h5>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="result.itemType == 'medic'">
     <div routerLink='/medic/{{result.itemId}}'>
       <h4>{{result.itemName}}</h4>
       <h5>{{result.itemLocation}}</h5>
       <h6 *ngIf="result.itemType == 'medic'">{{result.itemDescription}}</h6>
     </div>
   </div>
 </li>
```

When accessing the page the list gets printed like normal, but when I click on the item I want to access the page of, the route doesn't have the value attached, so instead of having '/hospital/hospitalId' I get '/hospital'.

**This only happens if I run the site using SpringBoot** but not by using ng serve. I already checked if it was a parsing error and it wasn't, the data gets stored correctly and it gets printed accordingly. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

`RouterLink` needs an array as value like this: `[routerLink]="['user', user.id, 'details']"` = ***"/user/8/details"*** as example.

```html
<ul class="list-group mt-3">
 <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let result of results">
   <div *ngIf="result.itemType == 'hospital'">
     <div [routerLink]="['/hospital', result.itemId]">
       <h4>{{result.itemName}}</h4>
       <h5>{{result.itemLocation}}</h5>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="result.itemType == 'ward'">
     <div [routerLink]="['/ward', result.itemId]">
       <h4>{{result.itemName}}</h4>
       <h5>{{result.itemLocation}}</h5>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="result.itemType == 'medic'">
     <div [routerLink]="['/medic', result.itemId]">
       <h4>{{result.itemName}}</h4>
       <h5>{{result.itemLocation}}</h5>
       <h6 *ngIf="result.itemType == 'medic'">{{result.itemDescription}}</h6>
     </div>
   </div>
 </li>
```

Comment: tried this solution too and it now goes to '/hospital/undefined'

Comment: Then show me code behind were you set the results.

Comment: The service does this `return this.http.get<Array<ListItem>>('/api/search', { params, responseType: 'json' })
      .pipe(tap(response => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastSearch", JSON.stringify(response));
      }));` and from what I can see from the debugger it does work

Comment: Yes, but where you set the "itemId" value? I think it is `null`.

Comment: I get a list of ListItem from the http.get, stringify it and set it in the session. Then get it back and parse it in an object, if I print the JSON string the ID it's there, if I open the search page the list gets printed, with all the other variable accessible via {{result.itemName}} etc. But if I pass the value in the routerLink it's undefined for some reason. As I said already this only happens when I use the site by booting Spring, but doesn't happen when I use ng serve

Comment: So apparently there was a spelling problem in the backend. The controller sent an array with itemID instead of itemId